# Using south dependent apps with django 1.7 new migration system

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-migrations

I want to use django-taggit but the [docs](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) said it's dependent on south. The django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) are saying that south(with improvements etc.) has been integrated into django 1.7. Does i con simply used south dependent apps like taggit with new migration framework, or i need do some shenanigans to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented [here](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/stable/):

> Since version 0.12.0 taggit uses Django migrations by default.

and [here](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id10):

> Backwards incompatible: Support for Django 1.7 migrations.

IOW : if you're using Django >= 1.7, you need taggit >= 0.12.0 (current is 0.16.something FWIW), and you dont need not have to care about south in any way.

Answer (score 0):

South has *not* been integrated in Django. What has been integrated in Django is a brand-new migration system, designed by the author of South. South migrations are 100% **incompatible** with Django's migration system.

So, in a broader sense, you depend on the app to supply migrations compatible with the new system, though there are some [shenanigans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#migration-modules) that allow you to create those migrations yourself. There are also ways that an app can support both, but there is no way to use South migrations in Django 1.7+.